XInt encountered numerous errors when importing Visual Studio
I am using a third-party library XInt (https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt) in C++ to manipulate .xlsx spreadsheet files. However, when running the program, it shows that there are many issues with the imported XInt header files. It seems that the header files are not damaged and the compilation with CMake is normal. I am using Visual Studio 2022 and have ensured that the library is correctly added to the project properties. Below is a screenshot of the specific errors reported by the compiler.
enter image description here
I tried rebuilding the project, redownloading and compiling the source files, and searching online for relevant help, but all attempts failed.

Please edit your question with the errors from the output log as text, in English. Not as a screenshot.

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically see: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
